# Drupal 7 pass value from javascript to webform hidden field

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-webform

I have a webform with some normal fields, but also some hidden fields which are set to *Secure value (allows use of all tokens)*, so I am able to use tokens.

How do I  pass values from JavaScript into those hidden fields so they are submitted with the form?

I tried using the `%post[f1]`, `%post[f2]`, and `%post[f3]` tokens, but I still don't know how to add those values with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some basic jQuery for this.

```
$('input[name=INPUT_NAME]').val('NEW_VALUE');
```

To fully comply with Drupal theming, you probably want to wrap this up in a Drupal behavior:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.CUSTOMNAME = {
  attach: function(context) {

     $('input[name=INPUT_NAME]').val('NEW_VALUE');

  }
}
})(jQuery);
```

...and of course change *INPUT_NAME* with the name attribute of the hidden input field and *CUSTOMNAME* with a descriptive camelcase name (e.g `ChangeHiddenValuesForm`).

As a final note: be sure to include this javascript file on the page of your form.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I overlooked the `Secure value` reference.

Anyway, if you want the value to be secure then you shouldn't be altering it by Javascript as anyone can change it to whatever he or she likes through the DOM... That's why Webform implements the `Secure value` feature: the value *does* get submitted along with the form but simply won't be sent to the end user's browser and hereby disabling possible abuse. (For the record: `Secure value` uses the '*value*' type from Drupal's Form API)

If you do want to change such a hidden value, you should opt for `Hidden element (less secure, changeable via JavaScript)` which already mentions its ability to be changed through Javascript and then use the Drupal behavior described above. Only if you do it like this it gets printed as a hidden input.

Comment: thanks but the `Secure values` don't seem to show up as normal hidden inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: With webform 4.x at least your input fields are going to be name with brackets and you need something like this to select them with jQuery: $('input[name="submitted[INPUT_NAME]"]').val('NEW_VALUE'); - I'm not sure if this is the case with older versions of webform. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: `the value does get submitted along with the form` - it doesn't seem to be in the regular form submit, though - any idea where ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some JavaScript then use `drupal_add_js()`, for example in `hook_preprocess_page()` in a theme.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) { 
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme.js');
  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); 
}
```